# TextView showing special characters incorrectly

Tags: android, string, character-encoding, textview

This may seem as a duplicate question but i read some answers from others similiar to mine with no result.

**The problem**
My app loads the list of installed application, then it shows the list and do the stuff it does (not relevant). In the list of installed application i noticed a problem with special characters, in particular with the "µTorrent" app.
The µ character is showing as M, so in the list this app will be called mTorrent (?!).

Here is how i load app names

```
        List<ResolveInfo> resolveInfos= pm.queryIntentActivities(mainIntent, 0);
for(ResolveInfo info : resolveInfos) {
    String name = info.activityInfo.name; // here it is!
}
```

What i tried so far

- Using Roboto font
- new String("µTorrent".getBytes("origin_charset"), "destination_charset"), with various combinations of origin/destination charsets
- URLEncoder.encode("µTorrent", "utf-8")

Note: even if i wrote "µTorrent" above i was using the String variable (used both to check the result)

**The question:**
How do i correctly show any kind of special characters in a TextView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the problem was due to the app label being converted to upper case, some characters that have no equivalent in uppercase get translated in other way like µ in M

Answer (score -1):

You will have to refer to this [utf-8 characters](https://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?number=1024&utf8=0x) and use them from your strings.xml.

**Sample**

```
<string name="Example">Example character \u0026</string>
```

Comment: I get he app names from the package manager...i have no control on how i get them, only on how i show them in textview